# Why there is no graph in the last subplot figure?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am writing this code to compute the normalized histogram for each patch of the image alone. But there is an empty figure for the last patch.

```
from skimage.io import imread
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
def patches(array, rows, cols):
    h, w = array.shape
    return (array.reshape(h//rows, rows, -1, cols)
               .swapaxes(1,2)
               .reshape(-1, rows, cols))
img= imread('example.bmp')
b = patches(img,256,256)
for i in range(1, o+1):
    plt.hist(b[i-1].ravel(),256,[0,256])
    plt.subplot(v, v, i)
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsCGi.jpg)

Comment: The last thing your script does is call ``plt.subplot()``, which creates an empty subplot.

Comment: ... or in orther words, move `plt.subplot(..)` ***before*** the `hist`.

Comment: it works fine thank you